# I want to search list element in the text file in python 3

Tags: python, list, search, element

I want to search list element in the text file.

First, I searched `HELP` in variables.txt file, I stored it in list `a`, 
which is `['setpoint_code_help;', 'position_code_help;', 'torque_code_help;']`
Now, I am trying to search element from that list `a` in `labels.h` file, but I am not able to find that element in `labels.h` file.

`labels.h` contains text like below:

```
#define setpoint_code_help                  "Enable or Disable the alarms of Setpoint"
#define position_code_help                  "Enable or Disable the alarms of Position"
#define torque_code_help                    "Enable or Disable the alarms of Torque"
```

I need to fetch the definition of those help.
Please let me know your comments on this.

```
d=[]

with open('D:\\HelpString\\variables.txt',"r+") as file:
    fileline= file.readlines()

    for x in fileline:
        if x.find('VARIABLE')>0:
            #a.append(x)
            print(x)
        elif x.find('HELP')>0:
            a=x.split()
            d.append(a[1])
            #print(type(c))
    print(d)
with open('D:\\HelpString\\6060E28C0101VAlabels.h', "r+") as file1:
    fileline1= file1.readlines()
    for x in d:       
        if x in fileline1:
             print(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need nested  for loops here: one to iterate over your list items to be checked and the other to loop over the lines of your file. You can do something like

```
with open('D:\\HelpString\\6060E28C0101VAlabels.h', "r+") as file1:
    fileline1= file1.readlines()
    for x in d: # <--- Loop through the list to check      
        for line in fileline1: # <--- Loop through each line
            if x in line:
                 print(x)
```

Comment: d is empty list at first, will not get inside

Comment: @Aaron_ab: This is the second part of the code. The OP appends data to `d` so it's not empty anymore.

Comment: @Bazingaa: I tried your solution but 'if x in line:' is not working.

Comment: @DeeptiKhanvilkar: Can you try `if x in line.split():` and tell me if it works?

Comment: I updated my code as per your suggestion:                                                       
with open('D:\\HelpString\\6060E28C0101VAlabels.h', "r+") as file1:
    fileline1= file1.readlines()
    for x in d:
         for line in fileline1:
            if x in line.split():
                print('true')
            else:
                print('False')                                                                                         I got output as 'False'

Comment: @DeeptiKhanvilkar: Your items to check contain ` semicolon at the end. So try doing `if x[0:-1] in line.split():` to exclude the semicolon

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, after reading the first file, you have a list, called `d`, which holds some strings.

What you want is to read some second file, and filter only the lines which have some string from `d`, right?

Is so, the problem becomes filtering a list of strings which have some string from another list(`d`)

Can do:

```
# second file, after building the "d" list    

def filter_lines_by_keywords(lines_to_filter, key_words):
   key_words_s = set(key_words)
   return filter(lambda l: set(l.split()) & key_words_s, lines_to_filter)


with open('D:\\HelpString\\6060E28C0101VAlabels.h', "r+") as file1:
    file1lines = file1.readlines()

filtered_lines = filter_lines_by_keywords(file1lines, d)
```

Running example:

```
d = ['word1', 'word2']
file1lines = ['line1 has some words', 
              'line2 has word1 and other', 
              'line3 has word2 and word1', 
              'line4 had nothing']
res = filter_lines_by_keywords(lines_to_filter = file1lines, 
                              key_words = d)

print(list(res))
>> ['line2 has word1 and other', 'line3 has word2 and word1']
```

Comment: Yes, what you understand is correct! i ll try your suggestion and let you know the result.

Comment: @DeeptiKhanvilkar - can you share if the answer solved your problem?